# GAE receiving Mail: can not get current user

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Following the GAE tutorial I managed to get it running and my servlet can receve incoming mails at local dev server.

As far as I understand when an inbound mail is sent to my application, an admin login will be used to send the request, But when i try to get current user using

```
User user = UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser();
```

the user is null, what's wrong here? In my app the admin is required to do some further procession to the incoming email.

Any help would be great.

My configuartion is as below:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>MailHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>


public class MailHandlerServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    public void doPost( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp ) throws IOException
    {
        User u = UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser();
        System.out.println( u );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe it will have a user as such.  These callbacks come from googles infrastructure and will have admin privileges, in the sense that google can call the /_ah/mail handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the response, In my mail handler servlet, I have to login as admin to do some further procession to the incoming email, or I will have no privillige to process users data. How can i achieve this?